# Поиск картинок строковыми функциями, php

Tags: php

Здравствуйте, возникла задача выбрать картинки с помощью строковых функций (без preg_match без прочих библиотек, dom и прочего), перебрал кучу вариантов, даже explode, strpos но получаются костыли.

Есть ли хорошее решение?

```
<html>
    <body>
        <img src='/photo/1.jpg' width='200'>
        <img src="/photo/2.jpg" width='200'>
        <img src=/photo/3.jpg width=200>
    </body>
</html>
```

Как выбрать эти картинки красиво только строковыми функциями?

Comment: Поиск ".jpg", потом поиск одиночной кавычки до и после, вырезание. Повторить с позиции закрывающей кавычки.

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов, Почему одиночной-то?

Comment: @vp_arth потому что в указанном примере внезапно одиночные кавычки.

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов, я вижу там 3 формы атрибутов

Comment: @vp_arth ну уж заменить-то одиночную кавычку на двойную автор, надеюсь, сможет...

Comment: Находим strstr комбинацию `'/` далее получаем позицию первой кавычки strpos, пропуская первый символ, убеждаемся что перед ней стоит `.jpg` Если это так то все от второго символа (`/`) до этой кавычки является именем файла. Берем строку начиная с позиции за той что вернул strpos, повторяем с начала

Answer (score 2):

Правильным решением будет использовать DOM парсер.
Это несложно и к тому же он есть в нативной поставке php.

```
$html = <<<HTML

<html>
    <body>
        <img src='/photo/1.jpg' width='200'>
        <img src="/photo/2.jpg" width='200'>
        <img src=/photo/3.jpg width=200>
    </body>
</html>
HTML;

$dom = new DomDocument;
$dom->loadHTML($html);
$imgs = $dom->getElementsByTagName('img');
foreach ($imgs as $img) {
    echo $img->getAttribute('src')."\n";
}
```

> /photo/1.jpg
>   /photo/2.jpg
>   /photo/3.jpg

Comment: при том, что ваш ответ отражает вполне разумный подход, он совершенно не сюда - *(без preg_match без прочих библиотек, dom и прочего)*

Comment: Тем не менее, любое корректное решение со строками будет на порядок сложнее. Также я настаиваю на том, что DomDocument не относится к "прочим библиотекам". Этот ответ в любом случае должен тут быть.